# Should we close old questions that no longer fit the SE question criteria?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

UX.StackExchange has been out of beta for several months now and there are a significant number of old questions from the early beta days as well as those that came across during the merger with UXExchange.com. Many of these questions are no longer valid questions for a Q&A website. They were let through originally because they have provided useful answers, and quite frankly we needed to get the user-base up in-order to make it out of beta.

So I put the question to the community: **should we now start to go back and close off old questions that do not fit with the [StackExchange good question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#what-makes-a-good-question) ideal that would not be allowed now should they have been asked recently?**

In particular I am talking about questions requesting a list of '[Examples of X](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=examples+closed%3A0&submit=search)' (of which there are literally hundreds), but there are many others that no longer fit the requirements.

*Note: I'm not talking about deleting them, just closing them off to discourage new questions in the same vein. The old information will still exist, and nobody will lose any of their reputation earned from questions that are closed off*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Absolutely. If they're open, they set a precedent that lets new users to post the same kinds of questions and then be upset about the questions being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, I've noticed on occasion a user will actually post a new answer to these posts. This should be prevented, in addition to setting the precedent that "this isn't allowed anymore".