# Should the edit feature reset the questions scroll?

Tags: feature-request, editing

One of the senior users on ux.stackexchange has been editing posts for a few hours. He may be doing to improve the quality of the questions when new users come to it; for their benefit and its all good in general.

However, currently this is putting all the old questions from '11 and '12 on the top and burying down the latest questions.

Should the edit question feature actually reset the question and show it up on the main questions page? Is there a reason behind that?

They can either be marked for review or something so that the moderator can see them, if that is the sole purpose of it. Otherwise, it is bogging down the current questions which I don't think is a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Bulk minor-edits (tag changes, spelling errors etc) are usually discouraged and would likely be detected if made by lower-rep users because each edit has to be approved and large bulk edits are likely to be unapproved (depending on the impact such action would to the site). Such edits are discouraged because of the issue you have identified.

However, higher reputation users earn the privilege to not have to have their edits approved. This is because it is expected that by the time they have earned such a right they will have been active on the site for quite a while and would have picked up the nuances and best practices in that time so would know when it is or is not appropriate to make edits.

These edits were done during the weekend, a notoriously quiet period on the site (and on most stack exchange sites as well) so should such bulk edits be made this is the time they should be done. Higher reputation users would likely be aware of the quiet periods so would be trusted to only do such activity during these periods. Yes, it does mess with the front-page, but that's not the only page on the site where questions are viewed - the [Questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions) page itself lists questions in newest order by default, so the front-screen only shows current activity.

Occasional general maintenance carried out at the weekend when the site is quiet isn't necessarily a bad thing, I'd be concerned if it was happening frequently or during the week but as it was quiet and not much was going on it's not really a problem (in my opinion) for this to occur every so often. In fact there are other suggestions for maintenance to do over the weekend, such as I suggested in [an older meta post myself](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/945/something-for-the-quiet-weekends-clean-out-the-clutter).

Comment: It was not the fact that he was doing it. Since, I mentioned that a senior user was doing it and I do understand the reason for the edits. I was just asking, if the edit needs to push the old questions to the top again? Can't we keep the questions in the original place irrespective of the last edit? (Basically sorted on the basis of last reply-time).